# rails 3 javascript not executed despite a text/javascript content-type in response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am performing an non-ajax GET request on a page. In the corresponding controller/action, I am returning javascript. However, this javascript is not being executed. Rather, it is showing up as text on my browser.

**The action being hit:**

```
def my_action
  render :template => 'shared/_alert.js.erb', :content_type => 'text/javascript'
end
```

**The js.erb file:**

```
alert("hello");
```

**Charles HTTP Request:**

```
GET /my_action HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.151.186:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: _session_id=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZGZhMjFkOWRlNDQ3ZThlYjRiMzljNzMyMjg0N2E2YmJJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFtZ05jUmsxZlRIQ1FCaVVLczVCeUF2STNtY1gzUzhucTk3alF4RjVsVklFPQY7AEZJIhRjdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWQGOwBGSSIpYjMwNzg5NzItNDQzNi0xMWUxLTk5YzUtNGY3NjNlNzJhZmIyBjsARg%3D%3D--e345e67c4b130d2f3e4bdb48bd3d5d4f892f8272
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Charles HTTP Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Etag: "9b9a7c156c510c98d7fd224227f7431f"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Runtime: 0.246125
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 15:23:09 GMT
Content-Length: 15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: _session_id=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlZGZhMjFkOWRlNDQ3ZThlYjRiMzljNzMyMjg0N2E2YmJJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFtZ05jUmsxZlRIQ1FCaVVLczVCeUF2STNtY1gzUzhucTk3alF4RjVsVklFPQY7AEZJIhRjdXJyZW50X3VzZXJfaWQGOwBGSSIpYjMwNzg5NzItNDQzNi0xMWUxLTk5YzUtNGY3NjNlNzJhZmIyBjsARg%3D%3D--e345e67c4b130d2f3e4bdb48bd3d5d4f892f8272; path=/; HttpOnly

alert("hello");
```

Could some help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: A non Ajax get is always just going to replace the current page with the contents of the response.

Comment: So, if I want the ability to give an alert using javascript if a certain condition is met in my action logic, then I need to perform an AJAX GET on the page which that action corresponds to?? That seems a little ridiculous... So if I have a before filter which checks whether the user is signed it or not and if the user is not signed in, I want to show a JS alert, then I will need to perform AJAX requests on all the pages having that before filter??

Comment: Not necessarily - the HTML page you return could have script tags in it that displays your alert.

Comment: Sure, but I was envisioning that a user is already on page X. User wants to go to page Y, but there is an error. And the user is alerted on page X via some JS. According to you, to achieve this, I will need to perform an ajax get request on page Y, correct?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't render page Y, possibly with an error message on it. You would need an Ajax request to be able to run js on page X but obviously that makes the case when you do just want to render page Y more complicated. I don't know what you accomplish by this

Comment: In a typical use case, I don't want the user to see the contents of page Y unless he/she is authenticated. If he/she is not authenticated, isnt it faster to show a JS modal on page X to login rather than redirecting to a sign-in page entirely? The former approach will require an AJAX get (if I am understanding you correctly) and the latter is possible with a normal GET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve what you stated in the comments: "User wants to go to page Y from page X, but there's an error." The standard way to do this is set the flash[:error] hash to your message, and redirect back to the referring page. In your layout you'd have some erb snippet like:

```
<% if flash[:error %>
  <div class='flash error'><%= flash[:error] %></div>
<% end %>
```

And on your controller you'd set up a before filter like:

```
before_filter :validate_user

def before_filter
  if <some condition is not met>
    flash[:error] = "Oops...you are not logged in"
    redirect_to :back   # or some_defined_path
  end
end
```